# Reference column does not get saved in unidirectional one to many relation hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have model object like order which can have multiple shipment packages. I am using hibernate (5.2.10). I wish to have one to many unidirectional relation between them , as shipment package object not necessary to have referece of Order object. This works till I only perform read operation. But If I wish to add new shipment to order, it fails.

```
Database tables :
t_order(order_id,..)
t_package(id, fk_order_id, package_id, tracking_no, create_date)  

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    .
    .
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_order_id")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private Set<ShippingPackage> shippingPackages;
    .
    .
}
@Table(name = "t_package")
public class ShippingPackage implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "package_id")
    private Long packageId;

    @Column(name = "tracking_no")
    private String trackingNo;

    ..

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createDate;    
    .
}

//service layer code
Order order = orderService.findByOrderNumber(orderNo);
order.getShippingPackages().add(new ShippingPackage(..));

Hibernate:
insert
into
    t_package_dispatch
    (create_date, package_id, tracking_no)
values
    (?, ?, ?)
Exception -     java.sql.SQLException: Field 'fk_order_id' doesn't have a default value
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you share the given error ? how do you add the ShippingPackage ? are you featuring  the add/remove method for adding shippingpackage in the Order class.

where do you instanciate the Set<shippingPackages> ?

Comment: Do you have `auto_increment` in `t_package` table on `id` column? If not, then add and try again.